# How to restrict Java generics type parameter in interface to certain classes

Tags: java, generics, types

I am creating a typed interface defintion and I want to restrict the possible values for the type parameter to a set of classes. These classes are existing already and are not under my control. Also, they are not related to each other through the class hierarchy.

So, for example, I have three classes A, B, C. My interface is `IMyFancyInterface<T>`. 
How can I restrict implementors of this interface and make sure that T is either A, B, or C only? 
Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: What is your intention, this is probably not the right design.

Comment: OK, let me clarify: I am creating something similar to the visitor pattern, where A, B, and C are the classes of the objects that are being visited. I say "similar to", because I am not able to modify A, B, C, so I can't add the accept(Visitor v) method, as per the standard implementation. Instead I wanted to create a typed vistor interface with a method visit(A o) so that the visitor classes can implement this, e.g. AVisitor implements IMyVisitorInterface<A>.

Comment: I should also there would then be a traversal class that holds the visitor implementations and calls their visit() methods on traversal of the structure that holds objects of type A, B, C.

Answer (score 4):

If `A`, `B` and `C` have a common super-type (let's say it's called `Super`), then you could do:

```
public interface IMyFancyInterface<T extends Super> { .. }
```

This way you should always implement this interface with a type-parameter that is a sub-type of `Super`, i.e. `A`, `B` or `C`.

If, however, `A`, `B` and `C` don't have a common super-type, you could create a marker interface (an interface with no abstract methods) and make them implement it. For example:

```
public interface Marker { }

public class A implements Marker { }

public class B implements Marker { }

public class C implements Marker { }
```

This way you'd be able to follow the approach I initially suggested:

```
public interface IMyFancyInterface<T extends Marker> { .. }
```

Comment: Thank you, Konstantin, for the suggestion. I had thoughts in the same direction, but unfortunately, these classes are not related and I am also not able to modify them.

Comment: In such case, I don't think you have many options, but just making sure that `IMyFancyInterface` is not improperly used (by being parameterized with some other type).

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If it's possible, consider the following code:

```
class MyClass implements IMyFancyInterface<T>
{
    <T extends A | B | C> void DoSomething(T o)
    {
        // what should the parameter o behave like?
        // o.???
    }
}
```

You can use non-generic methods if there is only a few A/B/C implementations:

```
interface MyFancyInterface
{
    void DoA(A a);
    void DoB(B b);
    void DoC(C c);
}
```

or cast in one method:

```
interface MyFancyInterface
{
    void Do(Object o);
}

class MyClass implements MyFancyInterface
{
    public void Do(Object o)
    {
        if (o instanceof A)
        {
            //do something with A
        }
        else if ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In your hypothetical example you might be able to call a method with an identical signature on all the classes. Though obviously a common interface would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I have now created a work-around by creating abstract classes for the three classes A, B, C which implement the interface. So, instead of implementing the interface, further visitor classes need to be derived from one of these abstract classes. Seems a bit verbose, but apparently there is no other way.

Comment: You said the classes are not in your control.

Comment: I meant abstract classes implementing the typed interface, one per class A, B, C as the type of the interface.